# How do I unlock augmentation for weapon/armor?

Tags: monster-hunter-world

This is my very first time playing a game of the Monster Hunter series.
I've read some guides and watched some videos (most from ps4 players).

All they say is that for unlocking augmentation option in the workshop, you must reach HR 50. Did so and still no options avaliable for augmentation.

Is anything else required (Optional quests, for example)?
Is it avaliable on pc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Augmentation is unlocked after receiving your first Warrior's or Hero's Streamstone. These are rarely obtained from the special rewards (the purple boxes) of tempered investigations of threat levels 2 and 3.

Comment: after clearing the HR 50 assignment (Tempered Kirin I think it was?) You are guaranteed to get one.

Comment: Not as far as I know. This question would be proof of that.